# Given a string, how to remove the run of the first character? (sed)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need a sed command that takes a string and removes all copies of the first character from the beginning (but not from the rest of the string).

For instance, AAABAC should produce BAC, because the first letter is A, so we remove the entire run of A's from the beginning.

My original thought was:

```
data=$(echo $data | sed 's/^.\+\(.*\)/\1/')
```

but this doesn't work (outputs empty string). If I replace the first `.` with a specific character, it will successfully work just for that character, but I can't get it to wildcard properly.

What I think is that the `.` matches the first character like I want, but then the `+` doesn't remember the letter I want and continues accepting every character until the end of the string, so that the parentheses contain nothing and so the whole string gets replaced with nothing. How can I initially accept any character, but then "lock in" that character for the `+`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
$> s='AAABAC'
$> sed -E 's/^(.)\1*//' <<< "$s"

BAC
```

- `(.)` will match the first character and captures it in group #1
- `\1*` will match 0 or more instances of same character

---

**Alternatively** here is a pure BASH way of doing the same:

```
$> shopt -s extglob
$> echo "${s##+(${s:0:1})}"

BAC
```

`${s:0:1}` gives us the first character of `$s` and `##+(${s:0:1})` removes all the instances of first char from the start.

Comment: Thank you, this is *almost* perfect. It doesn't work when there's only one of the first character, but changing the + to a * solves that.

Comment: yes that's right, answer updated. I was under impression that you don't want to remove if there are no repeats at the start.

Comment: Nicely done; while `-E` often makes a `sed` command work on both Linux and macOS, in this case it doesn't, because EREs on macOS do not support backreferences.
However, there is a POSIX-compliant BRE solution: `sed 's/^\(.\)\1*//'`

Answer (score 4):

To provide **a road map to the existing answers** with respect to **portability**:

<sup>Note: It can be inferred from the syntax used in the question and from what answer was accepted that *GNU* `sed` is being used, but the question isn't tagged as such, and it may be of broader interest.</sup>

- [anubhava's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40206037/45375) works with *GNU* `sed`, but not with (more) strictly POSIX-compliant `sed` implementations such as the one found on macOS.
- [Benjamin W.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40207264/45375) works with *GNU* `grep`, due to requiring the `-P` option for PCRE support, which other `grep` implementations, such as the one found on macOS, do not support.
- [soronta's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40207411/45375) works on *platforms that use the GNU regular-expression libraries* (most Linux distros), or, more generally, on platforms whose ERE (extended regular expression) syntax supports backreferences, as a *nonstandard* extension to the [POSIX spec.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)

  - Note that `=~`, Bash's regex-matching operator, is one of the rare Bash features whose *behavior is platform-dependent*, due to using the respective platform's regex libraries.

Here's a **POSIX-compliant solution** that should work on all modern Unix-like platforms, because it uses *BREs* (*basic* regular expressions), for which POSIX *does* mandate backreference support:

```
$ echo 'AAABAC' | sed 's/^\(.\)\1*//'
BAC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with grep, if your grep understands Perl compatible regular expressions:

```
$ grep -Po '^(.)\1*\K.*' <<< 'AABAC'
BAC
```

or

```
$ grep -Po '^(.)\1*\K.*' <<< 'ABAC'
BAC
```

`-o` retains only the match, and `\K` is a variable-length look-behind, removing as many identical characters from the beginning of the string as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Bash also supports regular expressions:

```
$ m='(.)(\1+)(.+)'; [[ AAAAABAC =~ $m ]]; printf '%s' "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
BAC
```

Valid for GNU ERE regex system library (varies with the system).